# OS X printing PDF super slow

Tags: macos, printing, adobe-acrobat

Using OSX and printing to both a Konica and HP printer, large PDF's (10-20 pages) print very slow using Adobe Acrobat reader or acrobat pro, on the order of 5-10 seconds per page.

If I use the built in apple preview program, pdf's print normally/fast, roughly 1 per second.

Looked around online, changing to print as image does not help.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the advanced print settings related to print quality/DPI/...?

Comment: how big in megabytes are they ?

Comment: Not that big, maybe 700 KB. Not even 1 megabyte. Like a 20 page text document.